# Check the frequncy of a character's consecutive occurences

Tags: bash, binary

I need a way (in Bash) to check the consecutive occurrences of a character, however it also needs to be capable of having a limit of occurrences before it is considered to be a second variable, in such a way that the larger set comes first. For example, say I have a letter in Binary, I would need the script to be capable of the following:

01111100

reported back as

03200

or

01001111

as

010031

or

01011001

as

0102001

and please **no awk, unless it is literally the only way this is possible in a bash shell**

Comment: This looks like homework.  What did you try until now?

Comment: It is not homework, though perhaps I should have included more preface: I am building a compiler for a base 4 alternative of binary meant to run in a virtual machine I've made, as I have become tired of compiling by hand. So far I have attempted commonly referenced methods with awk (i.e. {print}) which never work for anything I try, I have attempted sed, however the repetition of brackets and slashes is too convoluted when the line itself will be constantly repeated, and every method I find only count the frequency of the charater, with no denotation of its position/ whether it was consecutive

Comment: Awk -F'111' '{print NF-1}' did find the proper number of consecutive triplets of 1, however I need to process code in a linear fashion, character by character after it has already been translated into binary, and awk seems incapable of discerning the difference between 00111100 and 01111100, in both instances it simply returns "1" as the number of sets of three consecutive ones present, which doesn't help me.

Comment: Fair enough.  But, from your question, it is rather hard to figure out what you actually want.  And that's the reason for the downvotes (none of them is mine though).  I could **guess** from the examples that you want to count `1`s in a string until the counter reaches `3`, and then restart the count.  But the fact that you are limiting it at `3` is nowhere in your question.  Also, you probably want a full programming/scripting language, string processing is a pain in bash.

Comment: as a bash user, I was curious why your solution needs to be **in bash**. I've taken some "in bash" questions to the extreme, but -- do you really mean "something to run from the command-line" ? Or, just "not awk"?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller: I exclusively run and build on OS X and Debian kBSD variations, so for consistency of arg and option flags/and my own stubborn slightly nostalgic habbit I only use Bash, no Csh, Zsh, or Bourne shells for me :P in terms of awk I have literally never been able to get it to work properly for anything, thus the "not awk".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind perl, you could

- match instances of a single zero or a sequence of 1 to 3 ones
- map the zeros to themselves and the ones sequences to their lengths

e.g.

```
perl -lne '@runs = $_ =~ /(0|1{1,3})/g; print map { $_==0 ? $_ : length $_ } @runs'
```

Testing with the provided strings:

```
cat << EOF | \
  perl -lne '@runs = $_ =~ /(0|1{1,3})/g; print map { $_==0 ? $_ : length $_ } @runs'
01111100
01001111
01011001
EOF
```

outputs

```
03200
010031
0102001
```

---

If perl is not an option, you could do the same with other regular expression tools e.g. with grep and a bash array

```
mapfile -t runs < <(echo '01111100' | grep -Eo '0|1{1,3}')
```

then

```
for r in "${runs[@]}"; do ((r == 0)) && printf '0' || printf '%d' "${#r}"; done; printf '\n'
03200
```

Comment: Danke! This is exactly what I was looking for, works perfectly!